# Replace single line-feed characters, keep multiples

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am parsing a text file and want to remove all in-paragraph line breaks, while actually keeping the double line feeds that form new paragraphs.  e.g.

**This is my first poem\nthat does not make sense\nhow far should it go\nnobody can know.\n\nHere is a seconds\nthat is not as long\ngoodbye\n\n**

When printed out, this should look like this:

```
This is my first poem
that does not make sense
how far should it go
nobody can know.

Here is a seconds
that is not as long
goodbye
```

should become

**This is my first poem that does not make sense how far should it go nobody can know.\n\nHere is a seconds that is not as long goodbye\n\n**

Again, when printed, it should look like:

```
This is my first poem that does not make sense how far should it go nobody can know.

Here is a seconds that is not as long goodbye
```

The trick here is in removing single occurrances of '\n', while keeping the double line feed '\n\n', AND in preserving white space (i.e. "hello\nworld" becomes "hello world" and not "helloworld").

I can do this by first substituting the \n\n with a dummy string (like "*$*$*$*", or something equally ridiculous), then removing the \n followed by reconversion of "*$*$*$*" back to \n\n...but that seems overly circuitous.  Can I make this conversion with a single regular expression call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may replace all newlines that are not enclosed with other newlines with a space:

```
re.sub(r"(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)", " ", s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MsiQ9w):

```
import re
s = "This is my first poem\nthat does not make sense\nhow far should it go\nnobody can know.\n\nHere is a seconds\nthat is not as long\ngoodbye\n\n"
res = re.sub(r"(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)", " ", s)
print(res)
```

Here, the `(?<!\n)` is a *negative lookbehind* that fails the match if a newline is receded with another newline, and `(?!\n)` is a *negative lookahead* that fils the match of the newline is followed with another newline.

See more about [*Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions* here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).